# How can I make selenium + python lines satisfy PEP 8 line length recommendations?

Tags: python, selenium, pep8

When running flake8 over selenium + python scripts, unsurprisingly, I get lots of warnings that the lines are too long.

The problem is that selenium methods often have long names, and css classes often have long names too. Here's an example:

```
modal_details = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[class="modal-details-respones-tab__icon-container"]')
```

A line like that is already at 112 characters without any leading whitespace.

Nothing in [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) gives a clear indication how this can be made both readable and split up into multiple lines to make it shorter.

What is the recommended approach?

Comment: What are are the warnings? Are you going over a certain limit, like 80 line length? Or just that the function name is too long?

Comment: Going over the line length limit.

Comment: If the line limit bothers you, you can always change it. Also, you can tell the linter to ignore certain warnings. e.g. `example = lambda: 'example'  # noqa: E731`. You can read more about it in the [docs](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/3.1.1/user/ignoring-errors.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case, you can do:

```
modal_details = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(
    'div[class="modal-details-respones-tab__icon-container"]')
```

PEP8 does give clear indication [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id17).

However, PEP8 is a style guide, not a strict set of rules. There are many other ways to do what I did above, which you can alter to your taste.